# w3c validator: local installation on windows

Tags: php, perl, apache, w3c

i am trying to install w3c validator locally on windows xp with apache server.
I am following this document
http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html

but when i validate some site i am getting this error

`SGML::Parser::OpenSP version 0.991 required--this is only version 0.99 at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 60.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 60.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an improvement made to the validator depends on a newer version of SGML::Parser::OpenSP then when the guide was written.

I assume you grabbed the "single zip file" containing all the modules you needed, which appears to be maintained on a non-w3c host (presumably by the module author).

I suggest upgrading to the latest version of SGML::Parser::OpenSP through PPM, and then reporting the bug through the feedback channel mentioned at the bottom of the page you linked to.

Comment: Yes i am using single zip file. I am not sure how can i upgrade sgml::parser to latest version. Can you please guide me?

Comment: I hardly ever use perl on Windows, and when I do I use Strawberry not ActiveState. So no. Just read the instructions for PPM. It has a point and drool interface anyway.

Comment: Active State does not maintain a PPM for SGML::Parser::OpenSP. I'm in the process of trying to figure out how to build it myself.